# How does NET.TCP (WCF) protocol work on top of TCP?

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I am troubleshooting a performance issue with netTcpBinding in a Self-Hosted WCF service and looking at the packets is not clear whats going on. On a new connections I sometime see an overhead of 200-300 ms  in a LAN connection (2 machines connected on the same switch). The TCP 3 way handshake is quick, but the next packet PSH ACK one takes 150+ms. There is no load in the servers, is just this one request.

Is this controled by the nettcpbiding settings, or is it something at the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the overhead is required by the application (although seems high). The problem with the connections closing to quickly, within 2 minutes was due to idleTimeout setting in connectionPoolSettings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788984.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what performance problem your running down other than the occasional overhead of 200-300ms when making a connection.

If the request is a first time request, the spinning up of the WCF plumbing will take a tad longer in those cases while everything is constructed.  I'm wondering if this is what your seeing?

For example, the first request on a new process host, you'll likely see a noticeable 'hit' on that first request.  Another thing to note is IIS (if thats your host) will typically cycle a worker process after 20 minutes of inactivity.

I don't believe that anything really in the [netTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731343.aspx) element would affect this behavior (that I know of off hand).

The application might also be doing some work (populating a cache) on that start up that could account for that lag.  If its caching, it might also need to refresh its cache occasionally, or have a cache miss and need to fetch additional data.

Otherwise, the majority of the tcp/ip stack tweaks tend to be in the Windows registry.  Check out T[CP/IP Registry Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921093.aspx) for more info.

HTH,

Z

Comment: The host is not IIS, is service relying on WCF. The problem is the 200-300ms overhead, and it a problem because the host is closing the connection after about 2 minutes of inactivity!